# Unit of work/repository managers for NHibernate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I'm a .NET developer by day, but have been working with Rails and Merb for the past year on my own side projects, so when it comes to MVC and ORMs, I'm more used to them and using ActiveRecord and DataMapper.

I'm getting started with ASP.NET MVC, and I like what I see in NHibernate and Fluent NHibernate, but looking for a little bit more around how to best handle the unit of work or repository type model.

I'd like something that is not huge on architecture.  I've seen some projects like S#arp Architecture, but it looks kind of bloated.

All I am really after is a simple way to manage connections and handling data retrieval/storage.  A simple guide or sample application would even suffice.

Comment: Are you using an IOC container? I know that Castle has some support for NHibernate via extensions.

It would really help to know what tooling you're using because the answer will change. Also if you're trying to support a single session across many page requests.

Answer (score 11):

There are a few components you can use for easy Unit of Work implementations:

- [NHibernate Burrow](http://nhforge.org/wikis/burrow/get-started.aspx) - part of the NHContrib project
- [Rhino Commons](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Commons.ashx) - Unit of Work implementation, documentation is in sample code, on the blog and on the web
- [Conversation per Business Transaction](http://code.google.com/p/unhaddins/wiki/Overview) - from Fabio Maulo, a primary nhibernate developer, with some [documentation on his site](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/01/using-conversation-per-business.html)

As for sample projects, [here](http://blog.pragmasql.com/post/NHibernate-20-Sample-Project-using-NHibernateBurrow-contribution.aspx) is one for Burrow. I am using Burrow for a project right now and it's working fine for me. Although I don't use them, there are repository classes that use the unit of work session management, so it is really easy to get going with it. I also use Fluent NHibernate and it's straightforward to get everything working together.

Comment: Quote "Fabio Maulo, an nhibernate developer...", I would say, he is THE nhibernate developer :-) Good answer anyway.

Comment: From watching the commit log and mailing list, I certainly can't argue with that. I actually typed it with a "the" initially and due credit should be given.

Comment: NHibernate Burrow link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

You might also be interested in [Castle ActiveRecord](http://castleproject.org/activerecord/index.html), which implements the ActiveRecord pattern on top of NHibernate, loosely inspired on Rails' ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1):

> All I am really after is a simple way to manage connections and handling data retrieval/storage.

Yes, NHibernate can be pretty verbose. I've investigated both the Unit of Work and Repository "patterns" (they're actually "facades" but that's another story) and wrote very simple implementations of them. They both greatly simplify NHibernate, but I'd suggest using the Unit of Work implementation since I feel it's generally more performant and easier to use than Repository. Download it and give it a try:

http://code.google.com/p/nhibernate-unitofwork-example/

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the example. I looked at your code. Your unit of work does not consider LazyLoading. What if the session is still required after the initial loading process? In your case, it is disposed by then.

Comment: Sebastian, thanks for reviewing my code. My UOW implementation actually does consider lazy loading and is quite compatible. I would suggest keeping the session open for as long as you need it, as there is no penalty for keeping it open. If you need to close session for whatever reason, simply open a new one and the lazy loading should work as intended.